# Trying to you =COUNT on 30 sheet workbook for exel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to put a count in to a 30 sheet workbook to track if a time is put in a cell, how would I go about writing the the formal for that ?

I think it may be `=COUNT(‘1:31’!I12)` with `I12` being the cell that I need the count of how many times a time `(exp (9:48AM)` is put in there.

Comment: The formula will work if your sheet names are all 1,2,3,4,...,31 and 1 and 31 are at the ends in order of the tabs on the bottom and they are all visible.  One more caveat, your time must be a number that is formatted as a time and not a string that looks like a time.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the regular `'` and not the stylized `‘’` like you have in the formula above.  Excel does not recognize them correctly.

Comment: Now if I use the COUNTA that would account if say some just put in time not using ctrl+; correct, there should be noting else in the space but a time , I just want to make sure its counted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Consider using *COUNTA()* instead:

```
=COUNTA('1:31'!I1)
```

as this will handle both numbers and text.

[image]

Comment: Now if I use the COUNTA that would account if say some just put in time not using ctrl+; correct, there should be noting else in the space but a time , I just want to make sure its counted correctly

Comment: @Greg Be aware that if a worksheet is moved out of the range (i.e. Worksheet `5` is moved to the end, after worksheet `31`, it will not be counted. Perhaps you should protect the workbook structure.